# Error in eigen(corr) : infinite or missing values in 'x' when making a 'Correlation matrix circles plot'

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, heatmap

I would like to make a correlation matrix like the one below. However, R keeps telling me

```
'Error in eigen(corr) : infinite or missing values in 'x''
```

[Correlation matrix circles](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Correlation_matrix_circles,152)

I think this may be caused by NA values in my matrix. However, when I try to remove them by adding

```
'na.rm=TRUE,' it doesnt seem to help

circle.corr( cor(Plant, na.rm=TRUE,), order = TRUE, bg = "gray50", 
    col = colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(100) )
```

I have already loaded the function provided in the link above

Is it possible to create a new data.frame with the NA's removed? if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without data is hard to help you , but the error because your correlation matrix contains `NA` and `eigen` can't compute the eigen values in this cases.

This should work :

```
circle.corr( cor(Plant,use = "complete.obs"),   # NA are removed
      order = TRUE, bg = "gray50",
      col = colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(100) )
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in cor(Plant, na.rm = TRUE) : unused argument(s) (na.rm = TRUE)  for future reference, how can I easily provide data to future posts?

Comment: you can use `dput(Plant)` ..more general you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The error you got  because you add `na.rm= TRUE ` in `circle.corr` call. I update my answer.

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Error in cor(Plant, na.rm = T) : unused argument(s) (na.rm = T), even when I use your updated code

Comment: @user1977802 I am sorry I read the help of var ...for cor you use the argument `use`. It is better to add to add your data like I showed you  before.

Comment: You might want to look at the `nearZeroVar` function in the caret package.